# Access not allowed to a static inner interface

Tags: java

I have the following situation.

```
package A;
class SampleClass
{
 static interface sampleInterface
 {
   ....
 }
}
```

Now when I try to import the sampleInterface from another package , jDev says 'access not allowed'. What could be the problem?

Comment: Make `SampleClass` and `sampleInterface` public?

Comment: @Pshemo Would making `SampleClass` public be sufficient? (Don't have an IDE handy to test that).

Comment: @DuncanJones yes, making these classes `public` will let them be imported outside of `A` package. Most important we need to make interface public, but since we will access interface via class we also need to make that class public.

Comment: `static` is redundant here. All nested interfaces are implicitly static.

Comment: That is actully really stupid Pshemo and Duncan said the right answer and all "real answers" are copied -.-' most of them dont event know what java is!

Comment: @Gerret:  I don't mean to sound chatty, but I don't see your answer down here.  Just because the answer is pretty straightforward doesn't mean that there isn't more to the problem than meets the eye.

Comment: @Makoto yea your 100% right but if there already 4 times the right answer and 10 min after that someone post somthing like this `"Change visibility of the class and the interface to public. It will work for sure."` It is surely copied and he dosent have a knowledge of that in my eys. If someone post it like  you it is surly not copied and know what about he is talking!

Comment: So...downvote the answer and move on?  I don't see an issue here...

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the interface is seen as package-private (there's no visibility modifier, so that's the default).  Place `public` on the outer class and the interface, and it will become visible to other classes.

Just be careful - if you get caught in a situation where you have to do this:

```
public class Alpha extends Alpha.IAlpha {

    public void doNothing();

    public static interface IAlpha {
        public void doNothing();
    }
}
```

...you'll have an issue with **cyclic inheritance**, and your class won't compile.  In fact, you won't be able to use the interface at all.

Keep these rules in mind for exposing interfaces, classes, or enums:

- If you only need an inner class, interface, or enum for that particular *object*, then it's fine to declare it as static.
- If you need a class, interface, or enum accessible from anywhere *but* that object, then it's best to move it out of the inner class, and into its own file.

In general, interfaces are seen as APIs to conform by - there's really no benefit in having them as nested unless the scope of them is *extremely* narrow.

Answer (score 0):

Change visibility of the **class** and the interface to public. It will work for sure.

Answer (score -1):

When you declare a class without a access specifier it is by package-default. This means you can access that class in that package only.

If you want to access class from another package, make class **public**, i.e.

```
public class SampleClass
```

Similarly, in your case, as you want to access the Interface as well, you have to make that interface public as well.

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Not by itself. That and `public interface sampleInterface` will solve his problem.

Comment: @EJP I think I missed that part. Edited my answer. Thanks for pointing it out .